# Error 500: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault

Tags: java, rest, ssl, http-post, websphere-liberty

I have a client code where a post API works fine on my local machine but it fails on the deployed environment.

*Info: API is hosted in IBM WebSphere liberty Server*

***Error: Error 500: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault***

### Request URL:

https://myapp.dev.com/api/version1/postapi?pagesize=10&pagenumber=1

---

### Payload:

```
{
    "dateOne": null,
    "dateTwo": null,
    "code": null,
    "type": "ALL",
    "objInside": {
                    "prestr": "",
                    "start": null,
                    "end": null,
                    "letx": null,
                    "lety": null
    },
    "statusOne": [],
    "statusTwo": [],
    "players": [],
    "search": null
}
```

---

### Models

```
public class MyObj {
  private String type;
  private ObjInside objInside;
  private String code;
  private String dateOne;
  private String dateTwo;
  private List<String> statusOne;
  private List<String> statusTwo;
  private List<String> players;
  private String search;
}


public class ObjInside {

  private String prestr;
  private Float start;
  private Float end;
  private Double letx;
  private Double lety;
  private Double tempa;
  private Double tempb;
}
```

Comment: Hi - can you post some more details? It might be good to see the full stack trace (including any "caused by" clauses) as well as any warning/errors or other relevant messages from the log files.  Also, do your Java objects have public getters/setters for each of the fields being de-serialized?  One other thing to check is for any differences in the server configuration between your local and deployed environments.

Comment: @AndyMcCright I am not able to get logs of this issue from my server but on everyone's local machine API is working fine. There is all getter/setter's present. On the config part, I am not sure, as it is the client's server.

Comment: @AndyMcCright Hi I got the solution but I don't know why it worked. I just removed the toString() method from my entity class, It implements Serializable. 
It will be helpful if you have any idea and can share here, what is the relation between this

Comment: @AndyMcCright one more info the entity was updated. Someone added a member variable in it.

Comment: Without the logs, I won't know for sure, but it's possible that the `toString` method would throw an exception (like NPE or IndexOutOfBounds, etc.) and Liberty was invoking that method in order to trace it.  Once removed, Liberty would be able to trace it without exception.  In any case, I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: @AndyMcCright found the exact reason. Actually there was cycle dependency in the toString method of two entities.